# Bootstrap:Screen not showing properly in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

First screen is from IE9 and above second is from IE8. In IE 8 right side going down cos of showing in mobile view (Look at the top menu)

Here is the header i am using

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Here is how i am using

```
      <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">LEFT</div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">RIGHT</div>
      </div>
```

[image: In IE >8 and other browser]

[image: in IE8]

Comment: Read http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to include https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond for one thing to handle IE8

Download that and get it into your codebase and that should fix the issue.